# Полнотекстовый индекс Mysql + PHP. Пара вопросов

Tags: php, mysql

Только начал знакомится ! Мой пример

```
$db_query="
SELECT count(*), 
MATCH (text,name_adv,key_words) AGAINST ('+ремонт  +россия' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as REL
FROM ".DB_PREF."advert
WHERE MATCH (text,name_adv,key_words) AGAINST ('+ремонт  +россия' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
   ." and hide='show' "
   ." and end_putdate > ".$GLOBALS["timeDayAdvert"]."   "
    //."ORDER BY REL;
";
```

1. Можно ли использовать полнотекстовый индекс для SELECT COUNT или только для обычной выборки (мой пример проверил -  работает и быстрее)?
2. Что значит в моем примере дублированная строка после WHERE и зачем это нужно (нашел на хабре) .Или она только для выборки без COUNT ?

`MATCH (text,name_adv,key_words) AGAINST ('+ремонт  +россия' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

3. В движке есть поиск по записям. Получается, если есть запрос в строке поиска , то значит я должен подставлять выборку из полнотекстового индекса,а если строка пустая - то простым селектом, без MATCH-AGAINST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли использовать полнотекстовый индекс для SELECT COUNT

Нет взаимосвязи. Совсем. Полнотекстовый поиск - это способ поиска, плюс опционально сортировка по степени схожести документа и поисковой фразы. Что вы будете делать дальше с полученным набором строк - всё на ваше усмотрение.

> Что значит в моем примере дублированная строка после WHERE и зачем это нужно

В `where` условие поиска, именно здесь ищутся подходящие строки таблицы и отсеиваются те, которые не содержат поисковой фразы. Повторяется условие поиска в `select` - там получается некое `float`-значение оценки релевантности. По этому значению можно сортировать выборку, чтобы документы более подходящие (по мнению полнотекстового поиска, не обязательно совпадающему с мнением пользователя) для поискового запроса были показаны выше.

Если `where` опустить - то вы получите все записи из своей таблицы с оценкой степени релевантности поисковому запросу.

Если делать `count`, как сейчас написано у вас с дополнительным получением ранжирования, то в `mysql` можно встретить два варианта поведения:

1. запрос вернёт ошибку `expression contains nonaggregated column` и не будет выполнен. Для mysql 5.7 это поведение по-умолчанию. Можно встретить и на более ранних версиях, если в `sql_mode` включен режим `only_full_group_by`
2. запрос будет выполнен, `count` будет по-прежнему содержать осмысленное значение. Однако функция релевантности - данные для какой-то любой строки, оставшейся после выполнения секций `where` и объединений таблиц в `join`.

Последний подвопрос я не понял.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ.  По 3 вопросу

сейчас выборка осуществляется с помощью `select * from ... where .. order by...`

в само условие выборки  подставляется значение $_GET['text'] - поисковое слово .. 

Получается , если есть поисковое слово, то мы делаем  с MATCH-AGAINST , а если  нет поиска - то просто выборка ?

Comment: Да, если пользователь не пытался что-то искать полнотекстовым поиском - то не надо его использовать в запросе. Всё-таки, это довольно тяжёлая штука и по старой особенности реализации очень сильно мешает использовать любые другие индексы.